# PHP PEAR - Problems with files with over 200 row

Tags: php, excel

good morning,

i have a problem with php pear, which generates excel sheets.
this is my php code:

```
<?PHP
include_once "/Writer.php";

    $xls =& new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
    $xls -> setVersion(8); 


    $format_titel =& $xls->addFormat();
    $format_titel->setBold();
    $format_titel->setAlign('left');
    $format_titel->setSize('14');
    $format_titel->setFgColor('grey');
    $format_titel->setBorder(2);
    $sheet =& $xls->addWorksheet("Tab_1");


    for ($A=0; $A<=59; $A++) {
        $Zeile++;
        $s=0;   

        for ($B=0; $B<=1; $B++){
            $Text_Daten_Excel =  $Daten_Excel[$A][$B]; //$s++;
            $sheet -> write(($A+3), ($B), "TEST TEXT", $format_titel);
        }
    }

    $xls -> send("Sheet.xlsx");  
    $xls->close();
    $xls->sendFile();  
?>
```

This code works fine.
A Excel sheet will generate.

But if I change the line number to more than 59

```
for ($A=0; $A<=59; $A++) {
```

the excel sheet will generate but i cant open it.
I get this message:

```
The file is damaged and can not be opened.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity... `$xls =& new`? What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer is a rather old library that can only generate Excel 5.0 and Excel 97-2003 binary formats, not current XML-based one. `setVersion(8)` stands for **97-2003**. Whatever software you use to open the file, it may get confused if you call the file `Sheet.xlsx`.

Comment: i remove the & in `$xls =& new` = same Problem. if i call it Sheet.xls = same Problem. PHP Version 5.6.8

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest versions of everything (pear/spreadsheet_excel_writer, pear/OLE, etc.) from their GitHub repositories. I've found endless issues in Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer that lead to corrupted files and were patched in unstable versions.

Comment: can you show me the correct download link?

Comment: [https://github.com/pear/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer](https://github.com/pear/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer)

Comment: new files = same problem

Comment: When I run your code as-is I get a corrupted file because it has several PHP warnings inside due to the PHP/4 syntax being used. If I fix the warnings it runs flawlessly no matter the number of lines (though of course I had to fake `$Daten_Excel` because I have no idea of what it contains. If warnings are not an issue for you that means that your PHP environment is not configured to display errors, which is a problem itself.